# Controller to jsp and viceversa java

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

I am facing issue from days and could not able to find a way to solve. Let me explain my problem, basically, I am receiving table object(table does not exist in DB but this table object is formed with a query across several tables) from DB to jsp which has several rows and displaying them in the UI. The code looks like below in jsp.

```
<c:forEach items="${someinvoice}" var="invoice" varStatus="status"> 
                    <tr>
                        <td><input id="cartcheckbox" class="case" type="checkbox" name="case" value="${invoice}"/></td> //here invoice represents a row in table which looks like someinvoice[Name=Mobie , location= US, actualTransferDate=null, scanserialCode=234335,1237787, modelNum=MIC 898989 ]
                        <td>${invoice.scanserialCode}</td>
                        <td>${invoice.modelNum}</td>
                        <td>${invoice.assetName}</td>
                        <td>${invoice.assettoLocation}</td>
                        <td>${invoice.actualTransferDate}</td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
```

I am getting **someinvoice** from my controller as below.

```
List<BeanClass> invoiceData = service.Dao();
model.addAttribute("someinvoice", invoiceData);
```

Now, if i check some rows from the displayed table on UI and click submit button should result a new page which should show selected rows only in table format. For this, when submit button clicked i took the checked rows into controller as below.

```
String[] checkeditems = request.getParameterValues("case");//here case represents all the checked rows in the page and checkeditems represents a list of row objects as String.
```

My real problem is, I can not able to convert this String array to my bean class type, so that i can easily send these checked rows to another jsp which displays after submit button clicked. This is irritating me for a while.

Can any one help me here, I struck here for a while.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to do the request.getParameterValues("case"). you can map you check box to bean using `<form:checkbox path="invoice.checkBoxListName" value="${choice}"/>.`

The above will populate the list in your bean class so that you dont have to externally assign the array to the bean.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: i hope you are using spring mvc. if so, please see the below link for the reference http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-checkbox-and-checkboxes-example/

Comment: I am already using spring tag libraries in my jsps. Do not put more confusions to the asked ones. I think you did not understand my problem. Show me an example, how will you read the checkbox selected row as same the row object of bean class type.

Comment: i am not sure if you have gone through the link which i provided. if you can see through the example that should tell you how to map the selected checkboxes to the bean.

Comment: That example would not helped me in my current problem.

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

```
var someinvoice= [];
$('input[name="case"]:checked').each(function() {
someinvoice.push(this.value);
});
```

send the **someinvoice** on submit.

On **Controller**

```
List<BeanClass> invoiceData =Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(request.getParameter("someinvoice"), BeanClass[].class));
```

It will return you the list of BeanClass object.